# How to use Routing in https oncall cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to add routing in a [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) like we do with the help of express-js in [HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) because I read somewhere that we can not use express in https on call functions?

Basically I want to call a single http oncall function and based on the route the function will decide which code to execute.

Answer (score 0):

There is no routing available for callable type functions.  Each function can only handle a single request from a web or mobile client and send a single response.  The capabilities are [fully documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).  If you want to apply some sort of conditional handling for incoming requests, you'll have to implement that yourself.  Express will not work.

You can see for yourself exactly what callable functions do automatically for you in the [protocol specification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).

If you want Express routing, you'll have to use a regular HTTP function with onRequest, as illustrated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps).